# How to remove a partially installed app on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch

There is a partially installed app on my Apple Watch and I can't find a way to remove it. I have removed all the my apps that I've installed using Xcode to iPhone and the Watch still shows an icon that you see when a Watch app is about to be installed on the watch (see the screenshot blow)

[image]

Comment: You should be able to delete it using Jiggle Mode after a reboot.

Comment: Reboot did get rid of it. Thanks. You should add this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: This happens for me with the Apple Maps app, so even Jiggle Mode doesn't help (I think because it's a non-delete-able app). I plan to try resetting the entire watch next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to delete it using Jiggle Mode after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Apple Maps Watch app was partially loaded, and the only solution I found was resetting the watch and restoring from backup. This corrected the issue.

Aside: you can figure out which app it is that is partially installed by going to the Apple Watch iPhone app and choosing App Layout. The icons will all be complete there.